# Weird behaviour using django localflavor CAProvinceSelect

Tags: django, forms

My first time using localflavor in django and got a strange thing today! I have a form and was trying to user CAProvinceSelect, however, dont know why It wasnt render anything, to ilustrade, this was my code:

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.ca.forms import CAProvinceSelect

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
  province = CAProvinceSelect()
```

After I got boring to try making this work, I changed my code to:

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.ca.forms import CAProvinceField
from django.contrib.localflavor.ca.ca_provinces import PROVINCE_CHOICES

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
  province = CAProvinceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=PROVINCE_CHOICES))
```

And it worked !!!!

My question here is, why? does someone got that before?! Shouldnt 'CAProvinceSelect' create a SelectField with that choices?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please see here: http://django-irc-logs.com/2011/aug/20/#113904

CAProvinceSelect is a widget, you need to use CAProvinceField to get output:
`province = CAProvinceField(widget=CAProvinceSelect)`